# Redirect requests from http://bor.ih.com:8090 to http://bor.ih.com:8090/a/b/c on Tomcat

Tags: append, tomcat9, request-uri

I am currently utilizing Tomcat for my application. The necessary DNS and firewall settings have been properly configured. My specific requirement is that when I type 'http://bor.ih.com:8090' into a web browser, I would like it to automatically append '/a/b/c' to the end of the address, resulting in 'http://bor.ih.com:8090/a/b/c'. This setup allows external users to access the server seamlessly without needing to know the complete address. I am operating in a Windows environment.
Thanks.

i tried requestURI but i was not succeeed.